# Firefox Beta and Youtube - no play nice

Tags: youtube, firefox-for-android

I'm loving Firefox Beta.  My current only problem with it is that when it encounters a resource that needs to be opened with an app, it does not do that.  Instead, it gives me the non-useful error message "This link needs to be opened with an application."  Youtube is a clear example.  The android browser knows to open Youtube videos with the Youtube app, but there don't appear to be any kind of user agent settings in Firefox Beta?

I already tried removing defaults from both Firefox Beta and Browser.  Again, Browser properly interprets the default application for youtube anyway.

I also don't want flash; I don't want to play the videos in the browser but in the youtube app.